# MOSS 2007 to Sharepoint 2010 migration

Tags: error, migration, database, content-database, parser-error

Steps followed for Migration:

1. Backup up of production database
2. Create New Web Application on SP 2010 farm.
3. Restore Production Database on SP 2010 Farm.
4. Create Solution in SP 2010 with Name Space changed.
5. Deploy new solution on the web application with migrated content database 
   **Up to this step everything is working fine**
6. Open a web part page from the library.
7. Remove old web part
8. Add new web part . .. Parse Error received [image: Screen shot of YSOD]

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you run Test-SPContentDataBase after restoring backups?  This will tell you if you are missing anything that might affect site operations.  Additionally after starting the upgrade process the logs will tell you if any sites were skipped. If you leave any installed in MOSS when you backup, you will need to install those features before attaching DB in 2010.  If you continue to have problems, you could deactivate / uninstall the offending solutions prior to attaching it back into 2010.  Then you could just load your new solution and activate it.

Some handy tools in addition to MOSS preupgradecheck and 2010 Test-SPContentDatabase:

http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WssRemoveFeatureFrom

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WssAnalyzeFeatures

http://sharepintblog.com/2011/06/04/exporting-solutions-packages-wsp-with-powershell/